# place polarity labels outside voltage source icon

Tags: circuitikz

This is the code that is producing output shown on first picture bellow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\draw (0,0) to [isource, -*, l=$9mA$] (0,3);
\draw (0,3) to [R=$1k\Omega$, -*] (3,3);
\draw (3,3) to [isource, -*, a=$2mA$] (3,0);
\draw (3,0) to [R=$7k\Omega$] (0,0);
\draw (3,3) to [R=$6k\Omega$, -*] (6,3);
\draw (6,0) to [vsource, a=$4V$] (6,3);
\draw (6,0) to [R=$2k\Omega$] (3,0);
\draw (0,6) to [vsource, a=$2V$] (0,3);
\draw (0,6) to [R, a=$3k\Omega$, -*] (3,6);
\draw (3,6) to [R, a=$3k\Omega$] (3,3);
\draw (3,6) to [isource, a=$8mA$] (6,6);
\draw (6,6) to [R=$5k\Omega$] (6,3);
\draw (6,3) to [short, i=$I_A$] (5.2,3);
\draw (3,3) to [short, i=$I_B$] (3,3.8);
\draw (0,3) to [short, i=$I_C$] (0.8,3);
\draw (0,6) to [short, i=$I_D$] (0.8,6);
\draw (6,0) to [short, i=$I_E$] (5.2,0);
\draw (3,3) to node[ground, scale=1.4, rotate=45]{} (3,3);
\node[label=above:$V_1$] (0) at (3,6) {};  
\node[label=below:$V_2$] (0) at (3,0) {};  
\node[label=left:$V_3$] (0) at (0,3) {};  
\node[label=right:$V_4$] (0) at (6,3) {};  
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

My question is how do I place polarity labels (+/-) outside voltage source icon (like it is on second picture)?

[image: circuit1]
[image: circuit2]

Comment: Welcome! You can use an empty voltage source ( `esource`, I think, but check the manual) and add an explicit voltage with `v`. Maybe you have to disable the special treatment for sources (again, check the manual, I have no pc available now). But...are you sure? That notation is ambiguous, it could be a voltage source or the voltage drop on a current source...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of `override source vif`, `siunitx` syntax for all values and relative coordinates:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \ctikzset{bipole/override source vif=true}
\draw   (0,0)   to [isource, l=9<\milli\ampere>,-*] ++ (0,3)   coordinate[label=left:$V_3$] (A)
                to [R=1<\kilo\ohm>, f>^=$I_C$, -*]             ++ (3,0)   
                to [isource, a=2<\milli\ampere>,-*] ++ (0,-3)  coordinate[label=below:$V_2$] (B)
                to [R=7<\kilo\ohm>]                 ++ (-3,0)
%                
        (B)     to [R, a=2<\kilo\ohm>, f_<=$I_E$]              ++ (3,0)
                to [esource, v=4<\volt>, -*]        ++ (0,3)    node[right] {$V_4$}
                to [R, a=6<\kilo\ohm>, f>^=$I_A$]   ++ (-3,0)
%
        (A)     to [esource, v^=2<\volt>]            ++ (0,3)
                to [R, a=3<\kilo\ohm>, f>^=$I_D$, -*]   ++ (3,0)    coordinate[label=above:$V_1$] (C)
                to [R, a=$3k\Omega$]                ++ (0,-3)
%
        (C)     to [isource, a=8<\milli\ampere>]    ++ (3,0) 
                to [R=5<\kilo\ohm>]                 ++ (0,-3)
%
        (A -| B)   -- ++ (0.8,-0.4) node[ground]{}
        ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's literally the same thing I was trying to do with LaTeX. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, thanks for showing me the proper way of using syntax and for rewriting my code from scratch with relative coordinates. It really is a much better and cleaner solution than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Instead of `vsource, a=$4V$`, use `esource, v_=$4V$`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
\draw (0,0) to [isource, -*, l=$9mA$] (0,3);
\draw (0,3) to [R=$1k\Omega$, -*] (3,3);
\draw (3,3) to [isource, -*, a=$2mA$] (3,0);
\draw (3,0) to [R=$7k\Omega$] (0,0);
\draw (3,3) to [R=$6k\Omega$, -*] (6,3);
\draw (6,0) to [esource, v_=$4V$] (6,3);
\draw (6,0) to [R=$2k\Omega$] (3,0);
\draw (0,6) to [esource, v_=$2V$] (0,3);
\draw (0,6) to [R, a=$3k\Omega$, -*] (3,6);
\draw (3,6) to [R, a=$3k\Omega$] (3,3);
\draw (3,6) to [isource, a=$8mA$] (6,6);
\draw (6,6) to [R=$5k\Omega$] (6,3);
\draw (6,3) to [short, i=$I_A$] (5.2,3);
\draw (3,3) to [short, i=$I_B$] (3,3.8);
\draw (0,3) to [short, i=$I_C$] (0.8,3);
\draw (0,6) to [short, i=$I_D$] (0.8,6);
\draw (6,0) to [short, i=$I_E$] (5.2,0);
\draw (3,3) to node[ground, scale=1.4, rotate=45]{} (3,3);
\node[label=above:$V_1$] (0) at (3,6) {};  
\node[label=below:$V_2$] (0) at (3,0) {};  
\node[label=left:$V_3$] (0) at (0,3) {};  
\node[label=right:$V_4$] (0) at (6,3) {};  
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]